# How to make efi partiton and where should i mount efi partition in Kali Linux

Tags: partition, kali-linux, external-hdd

I have an external drive that i’m install kali linux into.there isn’t an Efi partition ,so how do you make it? And where should i mount it? In kali linux there is an option that says /boot, but when i installed Ubuntu and later deleted it, Ubuntu mounted it to /boot/efi. So should i use /boot/efi or /boot? Thanks, nullroot

Answer (score 1):

Kali seems to be based on Debian, and Debian's standard location for it is `/boot/efi`.

In Linux terms, the EFI partition (formally ESP = EFI System Partition) is just a FAT32 partition with a special type identifier in the partition table.

Ideally an EFI-bootable disk should use GPT partitioning, in which case there is a special type GUID for the EFI partition: `C12A7328-F81F-11D2-BA4B-00A0C93EC93B`. You probably won't ever have to type that in manually, as any GPT partitioning tool should understand that when you mark a GPT partition as bootable, it generally means applying that partition type GUID to it.

If you have to (or wish to) use MBR partitioning on your external drive, then you should use MBR partition type value `0xef` for the EFI partition.